# How do I make a boilerplate outlook signature for a company of 40?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am trying to create an email signature for a company. I am looking at several options for how to do this, as the users are not very computer literate...

The signature must include the person's name, title, phone #s, email address (bonus if it's a mailto link) and 3 pictures.

The 3 pictures are logos for linkedin, facebook, and twitter.

The main concern is that we want uniformity, and an easy way to change the 3 images/links across the entire company.

My first attempt at a solution was to use this code in the signature file:

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://www.ampedwebdesign.com/images/sig1.jpg');
position: relative; width:330px; height: 200px;">

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ampedal" target="_blank">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 20px; bottom: 17px; w
    idth:60px; height:55px;"></div>
    </a>

</div>
```

but it seems like outlook 2010 will not allow me to use divs.

I would just use the outlook editor to add some text, and images, and make them links - that works fine. But the main issue is that we don't want to have 40 users having to change their signature every-time we want to make a change to the signature images/links.

If anyone knows of a way to alter this kind of content dynamically - it would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Outlook 2007 / 2010 have very poor standards support. I'd recommend checking out the links below for some background reading, so you know what they are capable of:

[Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2007 use only Word as the email editor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933793)

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[Campaign to fix outlook](http://fixoutlook.org/)